# Как сделать модальные окна с увеличением картинок?

Tags: javascript, html

На одном изображении есть модальное окно, а на втором нету. На сайте 4 изображения в целом. Как сделать рабочее модальное окно на каждое изображение?

```js
var modal = document.querySelector('#main-modal');
var img = document.querySelector('#main-img');
var modalImg = document.querySelector('#img01');

img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
}

modal.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
}
```

```html
<div class="center-text">
                        <img src="images/photo-1.jpg" id="main-img" alt="">
                        <div id="main-modal" class="modal">
                            <span class="close" onclick=" document.getElementById('main-modal').style.display='none' ">&times;</span>
                            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-text">
                        <img src="images/photo-2.jpg" id="main-img" alt="">
                        <div id="main-modal" class="modal">
                            <span class="close" onclick=" document.getElementById('main-modal').style.display='none' ">&times;</span>
                            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```js
var modal = document.querySelector('#main-modal');
var img = document.querySelector('#main-img');
var modalImg = document.querySelector('#img01');

img.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
}

modal.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
    document.body.style.overflow = "";
}
```

```css
.main-photo img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.main-photo .center-text {
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.main-photo .left-text {
    text-align: end;
}

.main-photo .left-text button {
    margin-right: 40px;

    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(210deg, #97dbe8,#3f74a3);
    background: linear-gradient(210deg, #45c5de,#b9d2e8);
}

#main-img {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

#main-img:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.modal-content {
    z-index: 1000;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 40px;
    padding: 20px 100px;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

.modal-content {
    -webkit-animation-name:zoom;
    -webkit-animation-duration:0.6s;
    animation-name:zoom;
    animation-duration:0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
    from{-webkit-transform:scale(0);}
    to{-webkit-transform:scale(1);}
}

@keyframes zoom {
    from{transform:scale(0);}
    to{transform:scale(1);}
}

.close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #f1f1f1;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover, .close:focus {
    color: #bbb;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .modal-content {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="main-photo">
                    <div class="left-text">
                        <button>фото 1,2</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="center-text">
                        <img src="images/photo-1.jpg" id="main-img" alt="">
                        <div id="main-modal" class="modal">
                            <span class="close" onclick=" document.getElementById('main-modal').style.display='none' ">&times;</span>
                            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right-text">
                        <img src="images/photo-2.jpg" id="main-img" alt="">
                        <div id="main-modal" class="modal">
                            <span class="close" onclick=" document.getElementById('main-modal').style.display='none' ">&times;</span>
                            <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи достаточно одного модального окна, в которое будут передаваться src картинок при клике на них:

```js
$('.pic-wrap img').on('click',function(){ //при клике на любую из картинок
  let src = $(this).attr('src'); //получаем src этой картинки
  $('.modal-content').attr('src',src); //передаём в модальное окно
  $('.modal').addClass('open'); //делаем окно видимым
})
$('.close').on('click',function(){ //при клике на крестик
  $('.modal').removeClass('open'); //скрываем модальное окно
})
```

```css
.pic-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.pic-wrap img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 24%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: .3s;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}
.modal.open {
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
.modal-body {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
.modal-content {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.close {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  right: 8px;
  top: 5px;
  color: #fff;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .pic-wrap {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .pic-wrap img {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pic-wrap">
  <img src="https://funart.pro/uploads/posts/2019-10/1570458871_sportkary-170.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://krot.info/uploads/posts/2021-11/1635823006_5-krot-info-p-sportivnie-sportkari-mashini-krasivo-foto-5.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/mp/wallhaven-mp8qk8.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://on-desktop.com/wps/2017Auto___Lamborghini_Silver_sport_car_Lamborghini_Veneno_on_a_green_lawn_114675_.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<div class="modal">
  <span class="modal-body">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <img class="modal-content">
  </span>
</div>
```